# How can I get AdMob working for Android 2.3.3

Tags: android, admob

I followed the instructions for adding AdMob in my app and I compiled my code againest the suggested API Level and it compiles fine and when I try to test the application on either an emulator or my device it does not work, the application crashes as soon as I navigate to the activity that has the AdMob.

I searched and tried all the threads in stack overflow and non of them seems to work for me, I was surprised when other people who posted the same problem that they say it's working for them after someone has answered them but their solution doesn't seem to work for crashing the app which no one complained about.

I tried many versions of AdMob from 4 until the latest one 6 and non seem to work. Any help or suggestion where I am doing something wrong?

By the way, I even started a new app which is 4.0.3 and still the app crashes.

Thanks

Comment: Like Egor said, Android crashes rule #1: check and post your logcat. Also, a bit of code demonstrating how you're using the component wouldn't hurt either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure your place the library in the `libs` directory of your project, or in the Java Build  Path, explicitly `export` it so that it gets bundled into your .apk file when your app compiles.

Comment: I guess when added an external JAR it didn't add it to libs, so I had to copy it manually there.

Thanks a lot.